# single mysql query for select and update. if row is found then want to update otherwise it select row

Tags: php, mysql

any one ask single mysql query for select and update? if row is found then want to update otherwise it select rows?

```
$isTimeout=1;
$uniqueId=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_SESSION['sessionUniqueId']);
$checkSessionSql="SELECT userId FROM user_access_log WHERE 
sessionId='$uniqueId' AND isActive=1";
$resultCheckSession=$mysqli->query($checkSessionSql);       
if($resultCheckSession->num_rows>0){
    if($isTimeout==1){
        $updateSessionlog="UPDATE user_access_log SET isActive=0 WHERE sessionId='$uniqueId'";
    }else{
        while($assoArray=$resultCheckSession->fetch_assoc()){
          $userId=$assoArray['userId'];
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: `UPDATE` and `SELECT` are two separate functions that cannot be combined, but you can chain two queries with a semicolon `;`. Example `UPDATE User SET Id=2; SELECT * FROM User`.

Comment: ok but i read update with select queries some where else.

Comment: @vijay it is still an update query i.e. does not return any rows.

Comment: ok if possible update the row if select query with where condition is return any rows?